# modified Bessel function for Speech enhancement Using MMSE in matlab

Tags: matlab, stft

I am trying to implement an algorithm proposed in an old research paper by Ephraim and Malah for my DSP course project. I hope someone can help me with this difficult question. For the clean signal Amplitude Estimator, they used the following equation:

[image]

I understand most of the variables in the equation except the Bessel function stuff. Why did they use a Bessel function in here? 
and most importantly, how can I implement it in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bessel function just turns up as a result of the MMSE estimation problem given the assumed statistical model (cf. Appendix A of the paper). This modified Bessel function is implemented in Matlab as [besseli](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besseli.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to me Matt.  I looked into Appendix A and also read about Bessli function in general and in matlab in specific, but I didn't know how to use it for zero-order and first order. Both have the same index of (vk/2), so in matlab I did besseli(0,vk/2) and besseli(1,vk/2) for I0(vk/2) and I1(vk/2) respectively! Is this correct?!!!  Please let me know

Comment: @Mona: Yes, that's correct.